# Can you tell me when data was inserted into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am using MS SQL Server 2008 and I have an sql table with some data that is inserted daily at 6 am by an sql job. The problem I have is that some data has been inserted separately into the job and I need to know when this data was added.

Is there a query I can run that will show me this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the short answer is NO, there's no magic, ad hoc SQL query that will let you go back after the fact and find out when a row was inserted.

If you want to know when a row is inserted, the easiest thing would be to simply add a date or timestamp field with a default value (like getDate()) that automatically fills in the date/time when the row is inserted.

There are, of course, SQL logs available that will let you track when rows are inserted, updated, deleted, etc., but those require set up and maintenance.

Third option would be to have the program that's inserting the data perform some logging.

Answer (score 2):

Add a date field to the table. You can give it a default value of `GETDATE()`

Then `ORDER BY` that field.

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, NewDateColumn
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY NewDateColumn
```

Comment: the OP did not mention anything about `OEDER`, but need to know when this data was added

Comment: @armen - yes, but when you view the data surely you want it to be ordered? I personally wouldn't want to go through 50,000 records looking for a specific date.....

Comment: i understand that, but you wouldn't order either to scroll and find the desired date in those 50.000 rows

Answer (score 1):

what i would do is :

```
/* add new column to keep inserted row date */
ALTER TABLE [schemaName].[tableName] ADD [RecTime] DATETIME;

/* update the existing rows with the current date since there is no way to guess their insertion date */
UPDATE [schemaName].[tableName] SET [RecTime] = GETDATE();

/* and set a constraint to the RecTime column to set current date on every new row added */
ALTER TABLE [schemaName].[tableName] ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_tableName_RecTime] DEFAULT (GETDATE()) FOR [RecTime]
```

then you can get those rows like :

```
SELECT *
FROM [schemaName].[tableName]
WHERE NOT(DATEPART(hh, RecTime) = 6 AND DATEPART(mi, RecTime) <= 20)
```

you can 'play' with '20' if you know how long sql job run

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to look at SQL **CREATE TRIGGER** to add the logic to know when the data is being added and log that info in another table for further actions. Without further details I am not sure we can say more than that.

Comment: I personally think a trigger here is overkill as a date column will suffice.

Comment: You are assuming it is safe to add a column. I am not. That is all :-)

Comment: why would adding a column not be safe?

Comment: There are many reasons why it is not always safe. As an example with some software written in Delphi 7 or before (not sure about newer version...) if the developer has written a DataSet with a statement SELECT * FROM tableABC and the structure of that table was modified by adding a column the dataset crashes when the data is queried from the DB. Another case is that often a column is added which is all fine and it all seems to work but this column is never updated because the code logic was not updated. Adding a column is not always safe.

Comment: I think that the application should be tested to accommodate the new column.  `SELECT *` is not advised and the columns should be explicitly stated to accommodate for any `dataset` errors.  I disagree with you saying it is unsafe. It does not introduce any security concerns, only that the application using it should be retested to verify the application works with the newly introduced column.

Answer (score 0):

As you're referring to data which has already been inserted, the answer is No, unless you already have a datetime column which has a default value of `GETDATE()`.  The best you can manage after the event has occurred is to look at the sequence of rows and determine that it was between two known times.